# Что такое "очевидность"?

Tags: литература, лексика

Поскольку в вопросе про Капитана Очевидность разгорелся спор являются ли ответы Чеширского кота очевидными или нет, возник вопрос, а что вы понимаете под очевидностью? Являются ли ответы Чеширского кота из диалога очевидными?

Непосредственно диалог:

> — Скажите, пожалуйста, куда мне отсюда идти?
> — А куда ты хочешь попасть? — ответил Кот.
> — Мне всё равно… — сказала Алиса.
> — Тогда всё равно, куда и идти, — заметил Кот.
> — …только бы попасть куда-нибудь, — пояснила Алиса.
> — Куда-нибудь ты обязательно попадёшь, — сказал Кот. — Нужно только достаточно долго идти

Comment: Почему вы игнорируете хвост ответа? Чтобы попасть "куда-нибудь" вовсе не надо идти _долго_ - строго говоря, здесь достаточно одного шага. Какова здесь логическая необходимость этого довеска - "достаточно долго"? 

Не забывайте, что Л.К. был математиком.

Кот на самом деле лукавил, и его ответ отнюдь не бесспорен. Если, например, идти строго на Северо-Запад, то никогда никуда не придёшь (будешь бесконечно приближаться к Полюсу по спирали).

Comment: >Если, например, идти строго на Северо-Запад, то никогда никуда не придёшь (будешь бесконечно приближаться к Полюсу по спирали).

**Не очевидное ** для меня заявление :-)

:-) Откуда идти? Куда идти? Почему на северо-запад? Какая разница, к примеру, с северо-востоком? **ПОЧЕМУ "никогда никуда не придёшь"?**

Вообще не понял.

Comment: @Nikolja, ну, почитайте что-нибудь популярное, занимательное по математике или по физике. Например, "Зри в корень" Маковецкого.

ps Разницы с Северо-Востоком в данном случае нет.

Следующий аргумент.

Участник вечеринки хочет получить бесплатный совет у врача: - Доктор, что вы делаете, когда у вас насморк? - Я чихаю. (Вариант: - Я обращаюсь за советом к специалисту)

Можно ли такие ответы оценить фразой "Спасибо, КЭП!"?

Comment: @stopkran, да, случай с доктором это К. О. в чистом виде.

А вот с движением по спирали не согласен. Даже в этом случае ты куда-нибудь придёшь, хотя бы по той причине, что "куда-нибудь" может быть чем угодно. Да и сомневаюсь, что в кроличьей норе можно бесконечно долго идти в одном направлении, по крайней мере это не очевидно :-)

Comment: Случай с доктором - не КО вообще (вопрос был риторический). Подкрепление:

На форуме программистов новичок спрашивает: - Как мне решить вот эту задачу? - и получает ответ олдфага: - Найми программиста! (варианты: "почитай документацию", "погугли", "займись уже делом!"...) - и ни один негодяй не посмеет обозвать олдфага КО.

===================================

"куда-нибудь" может быть чем угодно, кроме "никуда" (идите читать учебник логики! :-)

Comment: >"куда-нибудь" может быть чем угодно, кроме "никуда" (идите читать учебник логики! :-)

Ну так и я о том же, в вашем примере с северо-западом.

Ваше категорическое *"никогда никуда не придёшь"* мне по-прежнему непонятно.

Например, если из Москвы строго на северо-запад, никуда не сворачивая, отправится какой-нибудь летательный аппарат, то через некоторое время он может оказаться в Финляндии. Какое же это *"никуда"*?

.

А чтобы попасть на полюс, Северный или Южный, то лететь вообще-то нужно соответственно на север или на юг. :-) Очевидность?

Comment: Если вы так настаиваете - тот, кто идёт, находится нигде (поэтому Ахиллес, например, никогда не догонит черепаху). Тот, кто стоит, находится где-то. То есть, чтобы куда-то попасть, достаточно просто остановиться (и неважно, как долго ты шёл). Но пока ты идёшь, ты никуда не можешь попасть.

Comment: @stopkran, моя логика проста. По закону сохранения энергии для бесконечного движения Алисе нужна бесконечная энергия. Так как никаких перпетум мобиле в книге Кэролла не упоминается, резонно предположить, что у Алисы его нет, а следовательно когда-нибудь она вынуждена будет остановиться. Подходит ли любое место её остановки под определение "что-нибудь"? Да. Так что не нужно из героини детской сказки делать Зенонова Ахилллеса.

А приводить в пример олдфагов некого форума, по моему, некорректно. Я вообще мем могу употребить лишь по отношению к себе,но это не значит я и есть единственный К. О.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще-то приведенный диалог во многом философский, как и практически всё произведение Л.Кэрролла. Любой из эпизодов книги можно рассматривать и как легкое детское чтиво, и как мудрую философскую притчу. Именно поэтому такой жаркий спор здесь и разгорелся.

Алиса спрашивает куда ей идти, но не знает куда хочет попасть. Тогда и всё равно куда идти - это же очевидно! Такой лёгкий ответ! Любой ребёнок засмеётся, как могла девочка задать такой глупый вопрос.

Но, если есть желание, можно тут и пофилософствовать. Например. Человека не устраивает его сегодняшнее место в жизни, есть уверенность, что надо что-то менять. Но что именно? И тут на помощь мудрый Кот: прежде чем спрашивать куда идти, сначала определись, куда хочешь попасть. А если всё равно, тогда иди хоть куда-нибудь. И тогда обязательно попадешь куда-нибудь. Надо только достаточно долго идти.

Comment: Ага. Или тебе _будет казаться_, что ты куда-то попал.

«Безумец воображает, будто сидит в склянке, а сам стоит на мосту и смотрит на свое отражение в реке!»

Comment: Хороший ответ, @yupaz ! Понравился. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, тут надо разобрать само слово "очевидный" — "видеть очами". То есть, грубо говоря, "очевидный" — тот, который все видят или настолько хорошо знают/понимают, что в ответе вопрос-то и не нуждается.
Позволю себе несколько примеров:

[image]

[image]

Comment: А есть ли разница между "безбилетный пассажир - это пассажир без билета" и "если достаточно долго куда-то идти, то куда-нибудь придёшь?

Answer (score 2):

Из того же произведения.

> - Вот тебе вопрос! Как ты сказала, сколько тебе лет?
>   Алиса быстро посчитала в уме и ответила:
> - Семь лет и шесть месяцев!
> - А вот и ошиблась! - закричал торжествующе Шалтай. - Ты ведь мне об этом ни слова не сказала!
> - Я думала, вы хотели спросить, сколько мне лет? - пояснила Алиса.
> - Если б я хотел, я бы так и спросил, - сказал Шалтай.

Так чей ответ здесь "очевидный" - правильный Шалтая или неправильный Алисы?

Еще цитата - из Г.К.Честертона (рассказ "Невидимка").

> Вы наверное замечали, что люди никогда не отвечают именно на тот вопрос, который им задают? Они отвечают на тот вопрос, который услышали или ожидают услышать. Предположим, одна леди гостит в усадьбе у другой и спрашивает: «Кто-нибудь сейчас живет здесь?» На это хозяйка никогда не ответит: «Да, конечно, - дворецкий, три лакея, горничная», - ну и все прочее, хотя горничная может хлопотать тут же в комнате, а дворецкий стоять за ее креслом. Она ответит: «Нет, никто», - имея в виду тех, кто мог бы вас заинтересовать. Зато, если врач во время эпидемии спросит ее: «Кто живет в вашем доме?» - она не забудет ни дворецкого, ни горничную, ни всех остальных. Так уж люди разговаривают: вам никогда не ответят на вопрос по существу, даже если отвечают сущую правду.

Ответ не основной вопрос. Разумеется, ответы Кота не очевидны, раз Алиса сама о них не догадалась.

Comment: Согласен, что она о них не догадалась, но это не делает смысл этих ответов менее очевидным. Даже из отрывка видно, что про то, что при движении куда-то куда-нибудь попадёшь девочка знает, а вот про то, что тут на все вопросы отвечают строго буквально - нет. Поэтому под куда-нибудь, находясь в лесу, имела в виду ближайшую деревню или город. Это опять-таки заметно и в диалоге с Шалтаем. Алиса не говорит, - "я этого ещё не говорила", так как в нормальном обществе, говорить очевидные вещи попросту неприлично и довольно грубо (подставьте ответ Шалтая вместо Алисиного, чтобы в этом убедиться).

Comment: Реплика к теме. На одном сайте занимательных задач нашла такую:  
"У Билли день рождения 23 декабря, но он всегда отмечает его летом. Почему"  
Когда найдете ответ, скажите, очевидный он или нет. ;-)

Comment: @Docent, ответ простой, и для жителя, например, Австралии, более чем очевидный. Для жителя северного полушария ответ не очевиден, так как расходится с его бытовыми представлениями о природе.

Я согласен с Вами, что очевидность зависит от субъекта, но не согласен, что неожиданность ответа - это признак его неочевидности. Задавая вопрос мы всё-таки меньше всего хотим услышать прописные истины Капитана Очевидность

Comment: Билли живет в южном полушарии? Для меня - очевидный...
Сообразил раньше чем дочитал.  
  
Я вот лучше задачку придумал. Одна англичанка родилась в апреле, но вот уже пятьдесят лет празднует день рождения в июне. Почему? А теперь скажите, кому это очевидно?

Comment: @behemothus, видимо Вы имеете в виду Елизавету II, но она отмечает день рождения не в июле, а в 3-ю субботу июня. Я не знал ответа на вопрос, но если б нужно было бы ответить сразу, то не сомневаясь назвал бы именно её. Под очевидными я понимаю те сведения, которые заведомо известны интересующемуся. И южное полушарие и королева Англии могут быть неизвестны, по крайней мере не осознаны. Я со школы знаю про лето в декабре, но когда услышал в каком-то аргентинском фильме про весну в ноябре секунд 10 переводил в свои понятия.

Comment: Разумеется, я не для того придумывал, чтобы Вас поймать на незнании. Вопрос в очевидности.

Answer (score 0):

Повторю здесь свой ответ в антецеденте темы.
Иногда на странный вопрос (Алисы, например) и нужно ответить буквальной очевидностью как залогом и надеждой для синхронизации начала понимания. Тем более тогда, когда такой ответ только и может быть единственным. Что, по-моему, и делает Кот. Но из диалога не следует, что Алиса и сама знает и понимает очевидность ответов на свои вопросы.

Что такое очевидность? То, что бесспорно и без сомнений представляется правильным выходом или решением непосредственно по стечении обстоятельств в некоторой ситуации. Очевидно, что очевидность во многом относительна, зависит от убеждений и взглядов. "В наблюдениях удача благоволит подготовленным умам". Так что коллегиальная очевидность — понятие не бесспорное.

Comment: По Вашему Алиса не знала, что при движении в определённом направлении куда-нибудь да попадёшь или, что на вопрос заблудившегося можно так ответить? Если первое, то её реакция на ответ странная, если второе, то то, что в обществе не принято говорить очевидные вещи, из-за бесполезности информации для собеседника, не делает их менее очевидными.

Comment: "нас невозможно сбить с пути - нам пофигу куда идти!"